# Jmeter for pages having dynamic token

Tags: jmeter, antiforgerytoken

I am recording a set of pages using JMeter. Some of the pages have dynamically generated token stored in hidden field.

I retrieve this token using xpath extractor, query is 
`//input[@name='__RequestVerificationToken']/@value`, store it in variable and use this variable for next request.

I don't know why this request is getting failed. I have checked the request value in View Results Tree. In raw tab the value is exactly the same as that of hidden field and on http tab "==" is missing at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Andrey Bolatov, there is a visualization issue in Request HTTP Tab which has now been fixed (you can test using [nightly build](http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html).

This does not explain you issue.

To debug, add a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to see what has been extracted.

You issue may come from the fact that you didn't encode the parameter, read:

[Send Parameters With the Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

Comment: I have downloaded apache-jmeter-r1402973_bin.zip from https://builds.apache.org/job/JMeter-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/dist/. But when I run bat file a windows open and close.... Is there anything else I need to do run this zip

Comment: Follow nightly page build instructions

Comment: Any news on that ? If my answer was OK you should accept it so that it's helpful to others. Otherwise please comment. Anyway, feedback is always welcome

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in JMeter. I reported it here - https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54055